# Invite Users to Azure DevOps Project via REST API (PowerShell)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api, invoke-command

The goal of the script is to invite a user to a specific project in Azure DevOps via REST. Invoke Request was used to add a user with the appropriate permissions.

I'm able to successfully retrieve the Project ID via the script below:

```
$OrganizationName = "ExampleOrg"
$projectName = "ExampleProject"

$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($env:AZ_Dev)")) }

$UriOrga = "https://$($OrganizationName).visualstudio.com/" 
$UriOrga
$uriAccount = $UriOrga + "_apis/projects?api-version=6.0"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriAccount -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader 


$Project = $response.value | where { $_.Name -eq $projectName }

$ProjectID = $Project.id

echo $ProjectID
```

However, using the newly acquired Project ID to send the invitation is unsuccessful.

```
$AZurl = 'https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/ExampleOrg/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=7.0'
$AZbase64AuthInfo = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($env:AZ_Dev)")) }

$AZbody =
@{
  accessLevel = @{
   accountLicenseType = "Stakeholder";
  }
  extensions =  @{
      id = "ms.feed"
    }
  user = @{
     principalName=  "example@gmail.com";
     subjectKind =  "user";
  }
  projectEntitlements =  @{
      group = @{
        groupType = "Contributors";
      }
      projectRef = @{
        id = $ProjectID
      }
    } 
} | ConvertTo-Json

$AZresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $AZurl -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $AZbody -Headers $AZbase64AuthInfo

$AZresponse
```

Can anyone provide some insight as to why this is happening and what the fix might be? Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Hi, please read this: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the same issue when I executed your code. Then I modified authentication method to PAT token as below and it worked.

```
$OrganizationName = "vijxxxxx17"
$projectName = "testproj"

$PAT = "hwjsqvunxxxxxxxxxxxegy3tnnxw4uov5yqpb5a"

$AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")) }

$UriOrga = "https://$($OrganizationName).visualstudio.com/" 
$UriOrga
$uriAccount = $UriOrga + "_apis/projects?api-version=6.0"
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uriAccount -Method get -Headers $AzureDevOpsAuthenicationHeader 


$Project = $response.value | where { $_.Name -eq $projectName }

$ProjectID = $Project.id

echo $ProjectID

$AZurl = 'https://vsaex.dev.azure.com/vijaytcs17/_apis/userentitlements?api-version=7.0'

$AZbase64AuthInfo = @{Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$PAT")) }

$AZbody = 
@{
  accessLevel = @{
   accountLicenseType = "Stakeholder";
  }
  extensions =  @{
      id = "ms.feed"
    }
  user = @{
     principalName=  "xyz333@gmail.com";
     subjectKind =  "user";
  }
  projectEntitlements =  @{
      group = @{
        groupType = "Contributors";
      }
      projectRef = @{
        id = $ProjectID
      }
    } 
} | ConvertTo-Json


$AZresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $AZurl -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Body $AZbody -Headers $AZbase64AuthInfo

$AZresponse
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your results! My authentication method is set in an environment variable similar to your $PAT variable.

I was able to get the code to work by modifying the Authorized Scopes associated with my access token in Azure DevOps. I believe the "Member Entitlement Management" scope was not set previously.

Answer (score 0):

The code works as intended once the correct scopes are selected. Changing the "Member Entitlement Management" scope associated with the PAT allowed the code to run successfully.

Required Scope

[image]

If possible, testing with Full Access will also prevent this issue from occurring.